# JMeter: How to calculate maximum number of threads per machine

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

The JMeter manual says

> Your hardware's capabilities will limit the number of threads you can effectively run with JMeter. It will also depend on how fast your server is (a faster server makes JMeter work harder since it returns request quicker). The more JMeter works, the less accurate its timing information may become.

The question I want to ask is *How many threads can I run from a single desktop machine and still get accurate enough results*?  However, I realize that's going to depend on what we define modern hardware as, or how fast my application/site is, etc.

So, the better (but harder to answer) question is, how to I **profile JMeter** to know when I've gone beyond the thread/user count that it's reasonable for a single machine to handle?  Accurate deterministic methods are preferred, but anecdotal/rules-of-thumb are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I first suggest you follow best-practices for building JMeter test plans and running them:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Then once your test plan is built, baseline it on the JMeter machine:

- Monitor CPU (don't exceed 50%), swap (ensure no swap in/out at all)
- Check GC for no long pauses

And don't forget issues which make Test wrong can come from lot of factors:

- Networks issue between injector and application
- TCP stack issues on JMeter injector
- Components between the Injector and Application (Firewall, Load Balancer ...)